# How to make Zsh interpret \n in parameter expansion

Tags: zsh, array, newlines

I’m using [Zsh’s parameter expansion flags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags) to split a string into an array.

This works:

```bash
string="one
two"
array=("${(f)string}")
echo "${array[1]}"

# Returns:
# one
```

This does not work:

```bash
string="one\ntwo"
array=("${(f)string}")
echo "${array[1]}"

# Returns:
# one
# two
```

How can we make the expansion interpret the `\n` as a newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zshexpn` manual covers such manipulations; one option is the `e`
parameter expansion flag (in same section as your `(f)` split) but `e`
does a whole lot of things (parameter expansion, command substitution,
and arithmetic expansion) as part of making `\n` literal. Or maybe you
do want all those manipulations to happen?

```
% string="a\nb" ; print -l ${(f)${(e)string}}
a
b
```

More exact is `g` which processes only escape sequences as handled by
the builtin echo:

```
% string="a\nb" ; array=( ${(f)${(g::)string}} ) ; print $array[2]
b
```

Even more exact is to split only on a literal `\n`:

```
% string="a\nb" ; print -l ${(s.\\n.)string}
a
b
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. I did try `e` and `g::` but in the same parenthesis as the `f`. I now see they had to be nested. I could swear I tried the last solution, but it may have been `ps:\n:`. Do note that it seems to require `\n`, not `\\n`.